# Swift 3 migration EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) on casting

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

Can anyone tell why is there an exception on this casting?

```
func aSpecialMethod(colorRange: @escaping (NSNumber?,Int) -> [Any]!) {
    print("do something here")
}

let colorRange = { (param1: NSNumber!, param2: Int) -> [Any]! in
    return [UIColor.red]
} as! (NSNumber?, Int) -> [Any]!

aSpecialMethod(colorRange: colorRange)
```

Xcode displays the following message:

> error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION
>   (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Some context:

The actual code belongs to an iOS application but you can try this sample in a playground and the error will occur.

I'm migrating some code to Swift 3 using Xcode 8.2.1 migration tool. The casting is being suggested by Xcode, it builds successfuly, but when running the code from a unit test, it will fail.

Thanks for any help.

UPDATE

Cleaning up a little and found this:

```
func aSpecialMethod(colorRange: @escaping (NSNumber?,Int) -> [Any]!) {
    print("do something here")
}

let colorRange = { (param1: NSNumber!, param2: Int) -> [Any]! in
    return [UIColor.red]
} as (NSNumber!, Int) -> [Any]!

aSpecialMethod(colorRange: colorRange)
```

Error message:

> Implicitly unwrapped optionals are only allowed at top level and as
>   function results

So it has to do with abolishment of implicitly unwrapped optionals as parameters ...
https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0054-abolish-iuo.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, in Swift, you cannot cast a closure to another type with `as!`.
(You should take the wrong suggestion as a bug of Swift/Xcode and send a Bug Report to Apple.)

You need to modify the closure's parameter types and return type as declared -- `(NSNumber?,Int) -> [Any]!`:

```
    let colorRange = { (param1: NSNumber?, param2: Int) -> [Any]! in
        return [UIColor.red]
    }

    aSpecialMethod(colorRange: colorRange)
```

Or put the closure where Swift can infer the types and omit type annotations:

```
    aSpecialMethod { param1, param2 in
        return [UIColor.red]
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As I know it's not possible in Swift right now. And as for me it's not logical at all, if we talk about how closures work internally - they create class for each closure which stores parameters, so your code looks like that

```
class A {
    var param1: NSNumber!
    var param2: Int
}

class B {
    var param1: NSNumber?
    var param2: Int
}
```

And then you're trying to cast instance of class A to class B, a little bit oddly, right?